Why is the compiler complaining about declaration conflicts and functions not being declared that are?
I am compiling the following file as part of a much larger project:
subroutine GetSoftwareLicense
    ! Checks out a license for this instance
    use Globals
    use Licensing
    implicit none

    LOGICAL :: CheckoutSuccessful
   
    !**********************************************************************************************
    !******************* CHECK OUT SOFTWARE LICENSE **********************
    !**********************************************************************************************
    CheckoutSuccessful = initialize_license(1, 50)

    if (.not. CheckoutSuccessful) call NoLicenseExit(3)

    write(szLogText,'("Success!")')
    call GlobalWriter(0,.TRUE.,.FALSE.)

end subroutine GetSoftwareLicense


subroutine NoLicenseExit(iType)
    ! Exits based on there not being a valid license
    use Globals
    implicit none
   
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: iType
    CHARACTER(100) :: StringLoader
    INTEGER :: iret
   
    StringLoader = "License Error"//CHAR(0)
   
    if (iType == 1) iret = MessageBox(ghWindow,"License failed to be checked out."//CHAR(0),StringLoader,IOR(MB_OK,MB_ICONERROR))
! More such checks... Just display a relevant message based on iType
   
    iret = SendMessage(ghWindow,WM_DESTROY,0,0)

end subroutine NoLicenseExit


integer function GetCostForThreads(threads)
    implicit none
   
    integer, intent(in) :: threads
    integer, parameter :: baseline = 5

    ! Baseline
    if (threads <= 4) then
        GetCostForThreads = baseline

    ! Scaling
    else
        GetCostForThreads = INT((threads-4)*1) + baseline
    endif

end function GetCostForThreads


logical function UpdateOMPThreadCount(threads)
    use Licensing
    use Globals
    implicit none
   
    integer, intent(in) :: threads

    integer :: cost, actual_threads
    logical :: success

    ! Obviously
    if (threads <= 1) then
        actual_threads = 1
    else
        actual_threads = threads
    endif

    ! Get cost
    cost = GetCostForThreads(actual_threads)

    ! Check with licensing
    success = update_cost(cost)
    if (success) then
        call omp_set_num_threads(actual_threads)
    else
        call GlobalErrorHandler(14)
    endif

    UpdateOMPThreadCount = success

end function UpdateOMPThreadCount

When compiling, I get the following error messages:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type. [GETCOSTFORTHREADS] Licenses.f90
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error error #5508: Declaration of routine 'NOLICENSEEXIT' conflicts with a previous declaration Licenses.f90

Why are these popping up? I have clearly declared GetCostForThreads, and nowhere else have I declared NoLicenseExit. I've tried rebuilding the solution multiple times. I've also tried deleting the entire "Debug" directory. Neither works. These are the only error messages that appear when compiling the entire project.

I doubt anyone can help.  We have no idea what is contained in the modules licensing and globals.

Where in UpdateOMPThreadCount have you ("clearly" or otherwise) declared the type of GetCostForThreads?

@francescalus GetCostForThreads is a function defined just above UpdateOMPThreadCount

I didn't ask where you declared the function GetCostForThreads, I asked where in UpdateOMPThreadCount, where the function is referenced, you declared the type of that function.

@steve globals contains definitions (among other things) for szLogText, GlobalWriter(), GlobalErrorHandler()... licensing contains the definitions for initialize_license() and update_cost(). I have checked and NoLicenseExit isn't declared anywhere else in my code...

@francescalus I'm not quite understanding. What do you mean by declare the type of the function?

See the answer in the linked question for details.  As GetCostForThreads is an external function and you have implicit none, you must declare the type of the function (or better, give an explicit interface for it).

Oh interesting. I see. That I can handle then. Just for understanding, if I were to put all this code into a module, would that then mean that these functions are no longer external?

If one removes use globals and use licensing, the error is obvious.  You need to declare integer, external :: GetCostForThreads in UpdateOMPThreadCount.

Yes. By definition, module procedures are not external procedures (but will need to be accessible).
